# SQL simultaneously transforming foreign key? (MySQL 5.5)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a natural key and another with a foreign key constaint to it:

```
create table A
(
    id varchar(255) not null primary key
    ...
)

create table B
(
    a_id varchar(255) not null
    ...

    foreign key (a_id) references A (id)
)
```

I would like to execute a transformation on `A.id`, (in this specific case lowercasing it) and simulataneously on `B.a_id`.

Obviously if I do:

```
update A set id=lower(id);
update B set a_id=lower(a_id);
```

Than I will get a foreign key constraint violation on the first update.

Is there anyway to execute the two updates "simultaneously", or can you recommend another way to deal with this?

Comment: Isn't that what [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) is for?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Approach might be to Drop the constraint,

Perform Update Queries

Again, Introduce the Foreign Key Constraint.

Answer (score 0):

drop the constraint and re-create the constraint with ON UPDATE CASCADE

then execute the update stament on the parent table no child table would get modified.

```
 ALTER  TTABLE b ADD CONSTARINT fk_const 
 FOREIGN KEY(a_id) REFERENCE  a (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

now execute this update

```
 update A set id=lower(id);
```